# Editing CSS of WordPress theme that has been embedded

Tags: css, wordpress, background-image, image-resizing

Hi I am building this site at http://amy-and-duncan-are-getting-married.co.uk/, using the Aggregate theme on WordPress.

The problem I am having is the background on certain pages does not fill the whole screen and I am left with a blank white area, when in Chrome if I go right click and inspect element I can get the CSS for the image and add the code I want,

'background-size : cover;'

I have tried researching this but I have read that WordPress automatically creates this CSS, surely there must be somewhere I can go and edit this code.

Can someone kindly give me a hint or clue cause I feel I am tearing my hair out.

Thanks
Craig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log in to the back-end of your WP site

`websiteurl/wp-admin`

Then on the left side bar, go to:

`> Appearance`

`> Editor`

Then look for the stylesheets on the right, under:

`> Styles`

Then `CTRL + F` the code you need to change, for instance:

`#content-area`

then add to this selector:

`background-size: cover;`

Then click `Update File`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use inline style like

```
    <div id="content-area" style="background-size: cover;">
```

Or add an external style sheet in your wordpress theme and define `content-area` id like

```
#content-area{
    background-size:cover !important;
}
```

I think this will work for you